# Detecting initial/entry click on QT QPlainTextEdit widget

Tags: qt, keyboard

I'd like to detect a click into a `QPlainTextEdit` widget. The ultimate goal is to launch a virtual keyboard widget. BTW, the `QPlainTextEdit` widget is described in a QT ui file and loaded by `QUiLoader`. I've tried installing an event handler for the `QPlainTextEdit` widget in order to catch `QEvent::FocusIn` events. Unfortunately this event is fired repeatedly, and not just once.

Note: I'm using QT 4.8.

**Update**
I've found a [tutorial/example](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.6/tools-inputpanel/) that shows how to launch a software input panel for a text input widget. Unfortunately, the input panel closes immediately after opening. Basically, the event `QEvent::CloseSoftwareInputPanel` is fired soon after `QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel`.

Comment: Your approach is correct. Try to add debug output for both FocusIn and FocusOut. May be the widget is gaining and losing focus. Do you check `object` argument in your `eventFilter(object, event)`? May be you're encountering focus events from another filtered objects.

Comment: You're right. The widget is gaining and loosing focus (I wonder why). BTW, `QEvent::MouseButtonPress` is not raised on `QPlainTextEdit` widget (I tried).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to trigger a `QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel` event (see [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432707/raising-a-qt-qeventwindowactivate-event))

```
void InputPanel::saveFocusWidget(QWidget *oldFocus , QWidget *newFocus )
{
    // check if newFocus is not null or top-level widget or previous widget
    // check if newFocus is QPlainTextEdit 
    QEvent event( QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel );
    QApplication::sendEvent( newFocus , &event );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect just mouse press event, install event filter on the widget's `viewport()` widget. See `QAbstractScrollArea` docs for more details.

Usually FocusIn event must not happen repeatedly. May be you have called `installEventFilter` multiple times for one widget?

May be you still can use FocusIn event and ignore repeating events somehow.

Comment: The event filter is not registered multiple times for the same object (I've checked).

I've tried installing an event filter for the `QAbstractScrollArea` of `QPlainTextEdit`, and oddly the object argument of the event filter cannot be cast to either of the two classes.

Comment: Do you use `qobject_cast` to cast? Try to use it.

Comment: Been trawling the docs. There's `QInputMethod` class that can be used to query the virtual keyboard. I'm still trying to figure out how to work with it tho'.