# Raising a QT QEvent::WindowActivate event

Tags: c++, qt

This following is a follow-on to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432233/qt-widget-and-software-input-panel-must-both-remain-on-top).

I've got a Qt dialog window that contains a `QPlainTextEdit` widget, for which I've created a Software Input Panel (SIP), following the example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-inputpanel.html). In this example an input widget, e.g. `QPlainTextEdit`, must be clicked twice in order for the SIP to appear. This is because (see example) a `QEvent::WindowActivate` event is not raised the `QPlainTextEdit` is clicked.

The workaround that I'm considering is to raise a `QEvent::WindowActivate` event when a `QPlainTextEdit` gets focus. Therefore I'd like to know how if it is possible to raise a `QEvent::WindowActivate` event and how to do so -- assuming the workaround makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, on the qt-project.org [forum](http://forum.qt.io/topic/6317/softwareinputpanel-with-digits-only-how/2)

```
QEvent event(QEvent::RequestSoftwareInputPanel);
QApplication::sendEvent(newFocus, &event);
```